# Secure phpmyadmin site with nginx

Tags: ip, webserver, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have a server with many websites. The configuration is done with nginx.
I installed phpmyadmin and I add a domain name to open it in the navigator.
I want to restrict access to see it only when I am connected to my personal network or VPN.

I tried this :

```
server {
    allow X.X.X.X/24;
    allow X.X.X.X/24;
    deny all;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    root /var/www/data/phpmyadmin;

    index index.php;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP domain-name.fr;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate /fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /privkey.pem;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain-name.fr;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

but it does not work...

I also tried to put the allow/deny part in a location section instead of writing it in server part :

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  allow X.X.X.X/24; #local IP
  allow X.X.X.X/24; #VPN IP
  deny all;
}
```

It did not solve the problem...

Do someone know how to do that please ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration

> nginx first searches for the most specific prefix location given by
> literal strings regardless of the listed order. In the configuration
> above the only prefix location is “/” and since it matches any request
> it will be used as a last resort. Then nginx checks locations given by
> regular expression in the order listed in the configuration file. The
> first matching expression stops the search and nginx will use this
> location. If no regular expression matches a request, then nginx uses
> the most specific prefix location found earlier.

so following this statement `/login` only matches if there is no regex that matches. If you access `/login/login.php` for example, your `location ~ \.php($|/)` wins the election on who gets to handle this request.

**SOLUTION 1**

To fix your problem set this location ABOVE the `php location`

```
location ~* /login {
    allow 5.80.29.130;
    deny all;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

use

```
location ^~ /login {
    allow 5.80.29.130;
    deny all;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location explains that `^~` disables regex matching if this prefix string location matches.

Source: [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/833212/953775)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you just don't want phpmyadmin to be accessed from outside of your network. So if this is the case, I can suggest you to just change the port on which this service listens and this port will only be accesible from inside. Other option is to block access by ip, this should do the job:

```
server {
...
   location / {
        allow 192.168.1.0/24;
        deny all;
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Remove all access rules in nginx + redirect for ssl:

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    listen [::]:8443 ssl;
    root /var/www/data/phpmyadmin;

    index index.php;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP domain-name.fr;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate /fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /privkey.pem;
}
```

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want to do ! I tried this method but I got an 403 Forbidden Error....

Comment: Probably because you blocked yourself with some nginx rule, no other reason to give you 403. If you change the port you won't need any access rules and you can just remove  anything related with phpmyadmin, please check the answer.